# How to make a text with skewed line but not letters?

Tags: html, css

I have a skewed text in HTML/CSS.
Like this: (http://jsfiddle.net/UPeYT/)

```css
p {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-8deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-8deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-8deg);
    transform: skew(-8deg);
}
```

I would like the alignment of the text to skew but the words themselves to **not** be italic. How whould I do that?

Comment: What is 'ledder-like'? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: He means that it has to be indented from the left.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using rotate, than skew for this. That will rotate the text rather than skewing it...

Comment: Using `transform` transforms the element visually but not literally, for more information, read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248111/overflow-behavior-after-using-css3-transform/21305283#21305283)

Comment: not possible with css but possible with javascript. [link](http://www.csstextwrap.com/examples.php)

Comment: @Siyah, yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've built something that I needed, but I'm not sure if it is exactly what you need. Essentially I'm taking a paragraph, skewing it, then splitting each word into it's own span with the skew reversed. I'm sure this is horrid for performance on a repaint though.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHnUQ/4/)

CSS:

```
span {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-18deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-18deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-18deg);
    transform: skew(-18deg);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
p {
    -webkit-transform: skew(18deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(18deg);
    -o-transform: skew(18deg);
    transform: skew(18deg);
    padding:30px;
}
```

javascript (uses jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var words = $('p').text().split(' ');
    $('p').empty();
    for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
        if (words[i]!='') {
            $('p').append('<span>'+words[i]+'</span> ');
        }
    }
});
```

The HTML is simply a P tag with whatever content.

Comment: Seems not too slow even for not so small texts.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but I guess it's the only right answer:

This is not possible. Let me show you how I came to that answer. I tried it with `font-style: italic`, which should not change the text if the `skew` made it *italic* for me, but it does not make it italic by default. It's just the transformation of the `skew` that makes it this way. If you change the degree, you'll see it get's straighter. It rotates the text and than it looks like it's italic, but it is not.

Here is what I mean: **http://jsfiddle.net/UPeYT/7/**

You can see that it's very different than yours: **http://jsfiddle.net/UPeYT/10/**

You can wrap the lines in a `span` or `p` tag. you want to indent and give them a `text-indent` to achieve what you want.

Comment: Whould it be OK for performance? I worry if such a rough scripting solution would make it slow.

Comment: I thougth you proposed to add `text-indent` with `p` tag to every line. I don't how to do that without js.

Comment: Well, yes, that is an option and not that resource intensive if you use CSS AND it's the only place where you use it. But, if your whole site depends on it, yes, than it would be intensive. Even with `jQuery`. Note that the jQuery option is better if it's on the whole site.

Comment: Hm, I might do that with server-side code, but that might look messy. And the other problem is how to split a single big paragraph into separate lines?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

I append parent to `<p>` element and apply the opposite!

see: http://jsfiddle.net/joseapl/UPeYT/9/

Comment: No, I ment lines themself, not the background/parent.